# How to search data in the TextBox in C# From using two different SQL tables in the Same Textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to display/search the value from the text/search box in my C# form.

I have two tables, one for the customer and the other for the supplier. I want to retrieve the data from both the tables, depending on the value inserted on the search box.

Thereforeand I have used the stored procedure with the inner join, to connect both the tables so that I can get the data from both of them.

However, I get an error which says that there are too many arguments in the store procedure, even though there are not so many.

Below are my codes for the C# and SQL, and I have also included the from, for the idea about what I am doing.

```cs
try
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SearchCustSupplier";

        if(Main_Form.TransactionType == "Purchase")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "Supplier");
        }

        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "Customer");
        }
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search" , "%"  +txtSearchSC.Text+ "%");

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);   
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);    

        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_ID", Cust_ID);
            txtSCName.Text = dr["CustName"].ToString();    
            txtEmail.Text = dr["CustEmail"].ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = dr["CustPhone"].ToString();
            txtMobile.Text = dr["CustMobile"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = dr["CustAddress"].ToString();

            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier_ID", Supp_ID);
            txtSCName.Text = dr["Supp_Name"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dr["Supp_Email"].ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = dr["Supp_Phone"].ToString();
            txtMobile.Text = dr["Supp_Mobile"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = dr["Supp_Address"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Customer/Supplier Not Found, Something Went Wrong", "Warning" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Here is the code for the stored procedure:

```sql
Create Or Alter Procedure SearchCustSupplier
    (@search varchar (300),
     @type varchar (200)
     --@Customer_ID Int,
     --@Supplier_ID Int
    )
As 
Begin 
    Select 
        C.Cust_ID, C.CustName, C.CustEmail, C.CustPhone, 
        C.CustMobile, C.CustAddress,
        S.Supp_ID, S.Supp_Name, S.Supp_Email, 
        S.Supp_Phone, S.Supp_Mobile, S.Supp_Address 
    From 
        Customer As C 
    Inner Join 
        Supplier As S ON C.Cust_ID = S.Supp_ID 
    Where 
        C.CustName Like @search 
        Or S.Supp_Name Like @search
End
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Comment: Hi, I'm not going to downvote but have a look at this https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: In the code you send two parameters @search and @type to stored prodedure, 
however stored procedure `SearchCustSuppliers` has got only one parameter @search.

Comment: can you please help me with writing the code, shall i put that parameters @type in the store procedure?